# Increasing Java heap size in jGrasp

Tags: java, jgrasp, heap-size

Where specifically would I input the command "java –Xss 1024k MyProgram” to increase the stack size for a Java program?

Alternatively, is there a way to increase the stack size within jGrasp itself

I know similar questions have been asked, but I really need a very basic explanation, as I have only minimal command line experience and java understanding.

EDIT: Altering the max memory use in /jGrasp/bin/winconfig.exe does not seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For JGrasp, go to the actual location of your JGraps application. Like the one that has folders called bin, data, etc. Open up bin and you should see near the bottom an application called winconfig (not the portable one). Double click and open, there should be a screen pop up talking about memory use. Set to 1024 and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I set it to 2048 (2GB), which I would think would be more than enough RAM to get the job done, but it still isn't working. Other resources have suggested that I need to alter the MINIMUM allotted memory, not just the max. Is there a way to do that it jGrasp that you know of?